# assign two classes to a generic constraint at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to assign two classes to generic constraint at runtime using an OR condition. I don't know if it is possible or not, as I am relatively new to all this.

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Employee Department
```

I want to assign TEntity either Employee class or Department class. Employee & Department are my two entities in DbContext. Please help me out on this one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's no such thing as an `or` constraint. The best you can hope for is an interface they both implement (or a common base class) and constraining to that instead

Comment: Also: Entity Framework is *already* an implementation of both a generic repository and a UOW. Don't fall into the very common trap of trying to create yet another repository wrapper around it

Comment: You can maintain a base class for `Employee` and `Department` and use it as a constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first recommendation is: Do not use another generic repository on top of Entity Framework, because it already implements one.

In the other hand, I have seen cases where this make sense. If you are in one of those cases, consider using Generic Repository only for the things that you could apply to every single class of your model. As soon as your model object requires an special query, then create it's own repository for it.

for example, it might be that for Department you only do a ListAll(), then use a generic repository.

But let's imagine that for employee you might want to do more complex things, like ListAllEmployessUnderBossThatAreOnHolidays(Employee boss)

Then you could have this structure:

```
// All model classes inherit from this one
public class ModelObject
{}

public class Employee: ModelObject
{}

public class Department: ModelObject
{}

// This repository could be use for simple model objects that do simple operations
// For example, -ALL- Department operations are simple, and it never requires a 
// complex query. So i handle it with this repository to avoid code duplication with 
// other model objects that are also simple
public class IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : ModelObject 
{ }

// Employee has some complex queries, so I create a repository for it that might or 
// might not inherit from IGenericRepository
public class EmployeeRepository : IGenericRepository<Employee>
{ }
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.